# SharePoint site as R directory

Tags: r, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have figured out a way to load files from a SharePoint site into R but is there a way to make the site itself a default R directory? I tried the shortcut and changing properties to the link but when I open R that doesn't work

Comment: Hey, Can you please eloborate on accessing files on sharepoint from R? I cannot find any reasonable answer. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way around it. You can't use the link for the intranet site, but if you use the syntax of \sitename\folder then R will recognize it as a directory and you can set it as such in the shortcut settings

Answer (score 2):

Probably there's no way, because Sharepoint folders are managed by Windows Explorer's shell extension. They doesn't exist in local file system, so R cannot see them.